# Avconv Can not resample 6 channels

Tags: conversion, ffmpeg, aac, libav

I'm getting a message, that it cannot resample 6 channels into 2 channel audio. This is the command i'm using to convert into h.264+aac:

```
avconv -i /var/movies/Some.movie.2010.BDRip.XviD.AC3.-HQ-ViDEO.avi -strict experimental -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 128k -ar 44100 -y -c:v libx264 -qscale 1 -s 640x480 -g 25 -r 25 /path/to
```

Exact message:

```
Resampling output channel count must be 1 or 2 for mono input; 1, 2 or 6 for stereo input; or N for N channel input.
Can not resample 6 channels @ 48000 Hz to 2 channels @ 44100 Hz
```

I have tried so many configurations, have tired experimenting.

Any video guru out there? Some tip would be awesome.

Thanks.

Here is avconv info:

```
avconv version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:02:36 with gcc 4.6.3
```

Comment: The error message indicates *"or N for N channel input."*, which suggests that if you have 6 input channels, you can only resample to 6 output channels. Maybe you need a different operation to downsample?

Comment: What options do i have in this situation?

Comment: [This](http://www.ilovemyjournal.com/?action=view_entry&eid=4490) suggests that downmixing in this fashion should work, all else being equal. Possibly a dumb question, but: have you tried first downsampling from 48KHz to 44.1KHz, and then downmixing to stereo from there?

Answer (score 2):

[Get a newer version](http://libav.org/download.html) that has libavresample, i.e. Libav 9 or git master.

Comment: Does Libav have a proper guide for compilation under Linux, or any static builds? If so, it'd be appreciated if you could link to that here. Thanks!

Comment: There are static linux 64bit builds at http://goo.gl/8rGRV . Don't know of any step by step compilation guide for Libav, but it's mostly just `./configure` and `make` / `make install`. There are some additional notes at https://libav.org/general.html .